# tableView adding/removing to second section objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have two sections in my tableview(iOS), where the first one is for the "favorites" rows. If you select the accessoryView it should add/remove the selected object in the "objects" array to/from "favs" array depending if the object already exist in the section.

The method I wrote almost works, but when I add a second row, or the same to remove it in favorites, the app crashes with this error:
`Terminating app due to uncaught exception NSRangeException', reason: *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]` 
The problem is that the index of the object in the corresponding arrays is not the same so I can't really figure out how to make this work properly.

Here's some code:

```
-(void)addToFavs:(id)sender{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *gesture = (UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender;
    NSLog(@"Tag = %d", gesture.view.tag);
    //if favorite section is empty
    if ([self.favs isEqualToArray:[@[]mutableCopy]]) {
        NSLog(@"adding favorite");
        [self.favs addObject:[self.objects objectAtIndex:gesture.view.tag]];
        [self.subtitlesFavs addObject:[self.subtitles objectAtIndex:gesture.view.tag]];
        [self.iconsFavs addObject:[self.icons objectAtIndex:gesture.view.tag]];
    }
    //if selected row already exist in favorites array <--HERE IS THE PROBLEM (I THINK)
    else if([[self.objects objectAtIndex:gesture.view.tag] isEqualToString:[self.favs objectAtIndex:gesture.view.tag]]){
        NSLog(@"removing favorite");
        [self.favs removeObjectAtIndex:gesture.view.tag];
        [self.subtitlesFavs removeObjectAtIndex:gesture.view.tag];
        [self.iconsFavs removeObjectAtIndex:gesture.view.tag];
    }else{
        NSLog(@"adding favorite");
        [self.favs addObject:[self.objects objectAtIndex:gesture.view.tag]];
        [self.subtitlesFavs addObject:[self.subtitles objectAtIndex:gesture.view.tag]];
        [self.iconsFavs addObject:[self.icons objectAtIndex:gesture.view.tag]];
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // left image
    UIImageView *image=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(7, 7, 30, 30)];
    [image.layer setCornerRadius:image.frame.size.width/2];
    [image setClipsToBounds:YES];
    if(indexPath.section==0){
        image.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[self.iconsFavs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }else{
    image.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[self.icons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }

    //fav image
    UIImageView *fav = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"favorites.png"]];
    [fav setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 25)];
    [fav setClipsToBounds:YES];
    if(!indexPath.section==0) {
        fav.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"unfavorites"];
    }

    //cell
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell){
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        cell.textLabel.text=self.objects[indexPath.row];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text =self.subtitles[indexPath.row];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:image];
        cell.accessoryView = fav;

        //Favorites
        cell.accessoryView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        cell.accessoryView.tag = indexPath.row;
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(addToFavs:)];
        tapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        [cell.accessoryView addGestureRecognizer:tapped];

        //favorites section contents
        if (indexPath.section == 0)
        {
            cell.textLabel.text=self.favs[indexPath.row];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:image];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text =self.subtitlesFavs[indexPath.row];
        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

## Update 1

I edited my code with "isEqualToString" in the if-condition but it still doesn't work to remove them...

Comment: what do you have in `self.objects` & `self.favs`?

Comment: How are you loading self.objects? The error says your [self.objects objectAtIndex:gesture.view.tag] is an NSString and you're calling containsObject on it which is not an NSString method

Comment: `self.objects` is a mutalbleArray with some strings and `self.favs` is an empty mutableArray

Comment: try `else if([[self.objects objectAtIndex:gesture.view.tag] isEqualToString:[self.favs objectAtIndex:gesture.view.tag]])`

Comment: okay thanks now I can add more favorites, but I still can't remove them... If I select a favorite one, it just adds another one instead.

Comment: then select the same favourite and it should get removed (_as per your logic_)

Comment: but I need to compare the selected string to the hole array, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: oh ok, then... hm... depends on your structure but my first suggestion would be to iterate through the entire array and compare with all (_but there'll be more efficient ways ofcourse_)

Comment: or... for now... try: `else if([self.objects containsObject:[self.favs objectAtIndex:gesture.view.tag]])` (_just a guess_)

Comment: If I choose the row that has index=0, then it works perfectly to remove it because the index of it is the same in the bort arrays.tThe index path for the corresponding strings in the both arrays are almost never the same... What should I do?

Comment: then I get this when I add another one:`Terminating app due to uncaught exception NSRangeException', reason: *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]`

Comment: ok, my bad, try this: `else if([self.favs containsObject:[self.objetcs objectAtIndex:gesture.view.tag]])` -- (___yes:delete, no:add___)

Comment: logic, logic, rethink your logic (_i am just shooting arrows in the dark right now_)

Comment: don't edit your question. the context changes. you, technically, have a different question now (_anyways..._)

Comment: yeah it's logic I know. I have to change the indexPath value for the self.favs to something else... hmm... yeah sorry but I tried the same code that you gave me here before with same errors:P so for me same question hehe

Comment: that `gesture.view.tag` smells bad. try changing that first

Comment: really struggling to get it working... I tried with `[self.favs removeObjectIdenticalTo:self.objects];` which at least doesn't make the app crash but doesn't remove anything really... What can I replace the gesture.view.tag to??

Comment: @staticVoidMan do you have any tips for my problem? :)

Comment: sure, i might. post these details in your question: **1.** slimmed down version of `self.objects` and `self.favs` **2.** why you're using a tap gesture (_seriously_) and how many tap gestures you have **3.** what you're trying to do with `gesture.view.tag` **4.** how many `tableViews` you have **5.** a basic overview of what you are trying to do and how you are doing it

Comment: @staticVoidMan see my answer, I removed the gesture.view.tag and instead used touch position in the tableview. then moved everything to `accessoryButoonTappedForRowWithIndexPath`. My solution doesn't give performance issues right?

Comment: i don't see any performance issue (_except for your `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:`_) but it can be done in an alternative way which (_i believe_) is alot more cleaner. for now, edit your question to include a pic of the current layout. (_precursor to what i am going for is utilizing just `-didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` or just `-accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:` but we'll know for sure once you add some more details_)

Comment: @staticVoidMan see layout in update. yes that's what I did now I used `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:`

Comment: yes, i saw you used it but it can be improved. what i meant was... no need for handling `touches`. anyways...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite similar to what you have but try this anyways:

**this be the `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method --**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
                                      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    //following commented line not needed
    //cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    // left image
    UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    [image setFrame:CGRectMake(7, 7, 30, 30)];
    [image.layer setCornerRadius:image.frame.size.width/2];
    [image setClipsToBounds:YES];
    [image.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor];
    [image.layer setBorderWidth:0.3f];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:image];

    //favorites image button
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 25)];
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unfavorites.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"favorites.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [button setTag:100];  //tag needed later
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(addToFavs:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
    [cell setAccessoryView:button];

    switch(indexPath.section) {
        case 0: { //is first section (favourite)
            image.image = [UIImage imageNamed: self.iconsFavs[indexPath.row]];
            cell.textLabel.text = self.favs[indexPath.row];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = self.subtitlesFavs[indexPath.row];
            [button setSelected:YES];
        }
        break;
        case 1: { //is second section (all clubs)
            image.image = [UIImage imageNamed: self.icons[indexPath.row]];
            cell.textLabel.text = self.objects[indexPath.row];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = self.subtitles[indexPath.row];

            //change state of button (thereby change button image)
            if([self.favs containsObject: self.objects[indexPath.row]]) {
                [button setSelected:YES];
            } else {
                [button setSelected:NO];
            }
        }
        break;
    }

    //separator -- do the following on viewDidLoad instead
    //[self.tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 45, 0, 0)];

    return cell;
}
```

---

**this be the `-addToFavs:event:` method --**

```
//No need for `-accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:` method
//it can be done in your following `-addToFavs:event:` method alone:
-(void)addToFavs:(id)sender event:(id)event
{
    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:currentTouchPosition];

    switch(indexPath.section) {
        case 0: { //is first section (favourite)
            //remove from favourites

            //get indexPath for appropraite row in second section
            NSUInteger i_indexOfFavInMain = [self.objects indexOfObject:self.favs [indexPath.row]];
            NSIndexPath *indexOfFavInMain = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i_indexOfFavInMain inSection:1];

            [self.favs removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [self.subtitlesFavs removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [self.iconsFavs removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            //handle second section button (for the appropriate row)
            UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexOfFavInMain];
            UIButton *btnTemp = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
            [btnTemp setSelected:NO];

            //reload first section
            [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        }
        break;

        case 1: { //is second section (all clubs)
            UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            UIButton *btnTemp = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:100];

            if([self.favs containsObject:self.objects[indexPath.row]]) {
                //remove from favourites
                [self.favs removeObject:self.objects[indexPath.row]];
                [self.subtitlesFavs removeObject:self.subtitles[indexPath.row]];
                [self.iconsFavs removeObject:self.icons[indexPath.row]];

                [btnTemp setSelected:NO];
            } else {
                //add to favourites
                [self.favs addObject: self.objects[indexPath.row]];
                [self.subtitlesFavs addObject: self.subtitles[indexPath.row]];
                [self.iconsFavs addObject: self.icons[indexPath.row]];

                [btnTemp setSelected:YES];
            }
            [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks I appreciate it. 3 things: **1.** I tried your code and it almost works, but the selected button gets unselected just after I click on the row in the second section. So no stars are selected in second section... **2.** Why should I not have all the code in `if(cell)` block? **3.** reloading sections does not look good at all, very ugly, and realod tableview the same, been trying to play around with `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:` but I always get an error(index out of bounds).. is there no way of just reloading the `accessoryView`?

Comment: @Tibbe : yes, those issues were bound to be there. i just wanted to ensure that the favourites add/remove properly

Comment: then yes it works, BUT you said I could remove `[button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(addToFavs:event:)  
               forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`, then I couldn't click at all

Comment: @Tibbe : oh. my bad. btw... do you want it on accessory view only? what about on entire row selection? that would be good

Comment: No the rows are connected to segues.. :P

Comment: @Tibbe : to fix those button images, try uncommenting the commented lines in the code (_in the answer provided above_) and check again

Comment: I did, but do you see that you use both button and btnTemp as the name in CellForAtIndexPath ?

Comment: @Tibbe : oh yeah, that was copy-paste typo. it should be your `button` object name and not `btnTemp`

Comment: Yes now that works! but I swapped the boolean because you made it the opposites selected hehe :P so now the reloadData animations problems and maybe fix the glitches

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45221/discussion-between-staticvoidman-and-tibbe)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution. Moving everything to `accessoryButoonTappedForRowWithIndexPath` and having four different cases did the trick. Also make sure to not have strings that are the same in the arrays otherwise it will remove all of them and you will get an index error.

```
-(void)addToFavs:(id)sender event:(id)event {
    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];
    if(indexPath!=nil){
        [self tableView: self.tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: indexPath];
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if ([self.favs count]==0) {
        NSLog(@"adding first favorite %@",[self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
        [self.favs addObject:[self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [self.subtitlesFavs addObject:[self.subtitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [self.iconsFavs addObject:[self.icons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    }else if (indexPath.section==0){
        NSLog(@"removing favorite %@",[self.favs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
        [self.favs removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.subtitlesFavs removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.iconsFavs removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }else if(indexPath.section==1 && [self.favs containsObject:[self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]){
        NSLog(@"removing favorite %@",[self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
        [self.favs removeObject:[self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [self.subtitlesFavs removeObject:[self.subtitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [self.iconsFavs removeObject:[self.icons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    }else{
         NSLog(@"adding favorite %@",[self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
        [self.favs addObject:[self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [self.subtitlesFavs addObject:[self.subtitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [self.iconsFavs addObject:[self.icons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }
    [tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{



    //cell
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell){
        // left image
        UIImageView *image=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(7, 7, 30, 30)];
        [image.layer setCornerRadius:image.frame.size.width/2];
        [image setClipsToBounds:YES];
        [image.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor];
        [image.layer setBorderWidth:0.3f];

        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        cell.detailTextLabel.textColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];
        cell.textLabel.text=self.objects[indexPath.row];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text =self.subtitles[indexPath.row];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:image];

        if(indexPath.section==0){
            image.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[self.iconsFavs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
            cell.textLabel.text=self.favs[indexPath.row];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text =self.subtitlesFavs[indexPath.row];
        }else{
            image.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[self.icons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        }
        //separetor
        [self.tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 45, 0, 0)];
        //favorites image button
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 25, 25);
        button.frame = frame;
        button.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unfavorites.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"favorites.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(addToFavs:event:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.accessoryView = button;

    }
    return cell;
}
```